# How do I turn a string of numbers into a sorted int?

Tags: java

If I have String x = "2016" how can I turn it into 6210 of an int type?

I'm trying

```
String x = "2016"
int v = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < x.length(); k++) {
    if (v < x.charAt(k) - '0') {
        v = x.charAt(k) - '0';
    }
}
v *= 1000;
```

But I have no idea what to do next

Comment: Call `toCharArray()`, sort the array, reverse it, and parse to integer.

Comment: I can only use for and while loops

Comment: Ok then, call `toCharArray()`, sort the array descending using your own sorting code, then build integer value from that. Hmmm.... That's pretty much the same as my first comment. Or if `toCharArray()` is not allowed, do what it does yourself too.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] stringVals = x.toCharArray();
int[] results = new int[stringVals.length];
for (int i = 0; i < stringVals.length; i++) {
        try {
            results[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringVals[i]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            //NOTE: write something here if you need to recover from formatting errors
        };
    }
 Arrays.sort(results);
 String sortedResult = Arrays.toString(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [Integer.parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

But you can not use chars (as a previous poster mentioned in their answer) as char is not compatible with Integer.parseInt, only strings are.

Try parsing your String into an array like so:

```
String[] numbers = x.split("");
```

Potential solution:

```
String x = "2016";

    String[] numbers = x.split("");
    Integer[] nums = new Integer[numbers.length];
    for (int k = 0; k < numbers.length; k++) {

        nums[k] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[k]);
                }

    Arrays.sort(nums, Collections.reverseOrder());
    StringBuilder strNum = new StringBuilder();

    for (int num : nums){
        strNum.append(num);
        }
    int finalInt = Integer.parseInt(strNum.toString());
    System.out.println(finalInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `java-8`

```
String reversed = Arrays.stream(x.split(""))
                        .sorted(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.reversed())
                        .collect(Collectors.joining());

int v = Integer.parseInt(reversed);
```